# Symfony2 Many-to-Many with attribute object persistance (Many-to-One/One-to-Many)

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, symfony-forms

I have looked a couple of question on stack overflow. Many questions seems to be close to what I am asking, but I can't find my answer throughout them. So here I am asking a brand new question.

Please feel free to ask me for more info if I omitted something important.

### Context

I am building a Symfony2 Web application that manages some users avalability to some events on a calendar. So I have 3 entities to represent that. "Utilisateur" that means user which is an extension of FOSUserBundle, "Evenement" which means event and an intermediary object that stores status of the relation between those last two. The intermediate entity name is "Disponibilite" which means availability.

### What I want to do

When a user clicks on an event on the calendar, it brings him to a page where he can specify if he is available or not from a dropdown list and then write a brief comment to motivate his decision. He then submits his availability and the server saves his availability for the event.

### Problem

In my form for submiting my availability, I can't seem to find a way to inject information about the related objects (Evenement and Utilisateur). I don't want to make an entity choice field since the User and Event are already chosen. I want to make a sort of hidden entity field. Is that possible? Is it the good way to do?

### Note

The user may or may not have a Disponibilite row in the database. If we look for availability of User A for Event E and there is no result, it means that this user has never given his availability for this event. In the case that there is a result, it means that the user has already given his availability and is currently modifying his availability for the event.

I am starting with Symfony2, so I may be missing something very basic

### Code

Here is the simplification of my code.

### Entity\Utilisateur.php

This is an heritage of the BaseUser from FOSUserBundle

```
class Utilisateur extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;
}
```

### Entity\Evenement.php

An entity that represents an event.

```
class Evenement
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Musique\GestionBundle\Entity\Disponibilite", mappedBy="evenement")
     */
    private $disponibilite;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

### Entity\Disponibilite.php

An entity that represents the relation between Evenement and Utilisateur.

```
class Disponibilite
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Musique\GestionBundle\Entity\Evenement",inversedBy="disponibilite")
     */
    private $evenement;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Musique\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur")
     */
    private $utilisateur;
}
```

### Form\DisponibiliteType.php

The for I use to get information about availability for a certain event for a certain user

```
class Disponibilite extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('disponibilite','choice', array(
                    'choices' => array("DispOui"=>"Disponible","DispCondition"=>"Incertain","DispNon"=>"Non-Disponible"),
                    'required' => true))
            ->add('raison')

            // Add entity field here? hidden field?
        ;
}
```

### In the controller

Action to load the view of DisponibiliteType (the form)

```
function disponibiliteAction($id){
    $repo_evenement = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MusiqueGestionBundle:Evenement');
    $repo_dispo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MusiqueGestionBundle:Disponibilite');

    $disponibilite = $repo_dispo->findBy(
            array('evenement'=>$id,'utilisateur'=>$this->getUser())
    );

    $evenement = $repo_evenement->find($id);

    if(count($disponibilite) > 0){
        $disponibilite = $disponibilite[0];
    } else {
        $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
        $disponibilite->setEvenement($evenement);
        $disponibilite->setUtilisateur($this->getUser());
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new DisponibiliteType(),$disponibilite);
    return $this->render('MusiqueGestionBundle:Calendrier:disponibilite.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView(),'evenement'=> $evenement));
}
```

Action triggered when the form is posted

```
function sendDisponibiliteAction(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $repo_evenement = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MusiqueGestionBundle:Evenement');
    $evenement = $repo_evenement->find($request->get('evenement'));
    $repo_utilisateur = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MusiqueUtilisateurBundle:Utilisateur');
    $utilisateur = $repo_utilisateur->find($request->get('utilisateur'));

    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->setEvenement($evenement);
    $disponibilite->setUtilisateur($utilisateur);
    $form = $this->createForm(new DisponibiliteType(),$disponibilite);

    $form->bind($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($disponibilite);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("calendrier"));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not so hard, actually. I've made it with just one action, if you want, you can split it like you did before.

```
function disponibiliteAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repo_evenement = $em->getRepository('MusiqueGestionBundle:Evenement');
    $repo_dispo = $em->getRepository('MusiqueGestionBundle:Disponibilite');

    $evenement = $repo_evenement->findOneById($id);

    if (is_null($evenement)) {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $disponibilite = $repo_dispo->findOneBy(
        array('evenement'=>$evenement,'utilisateur'=>$this->getUser())
    );

    if (is_null($disponibilite)) {
        $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
        $disponibilite->setEvenement($evenement);
        $disponibilite->setUtilisateur($this->getUser());
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new DisponibiliteType(),$disponibilite);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('post')) {
        $form->submit($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if ($disponibilite->getId() === null) {
                $em->persist($disponibilite);
            }
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("calendrier"));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MusiqueGestionBundle:Calendrier:disponibilite.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView(),'evenement'=> $evenement));
}
```

Comment: When I do    $disponibilite->setEvenement($evenement)    does the entity info gets passed into the POST from the form? Only the Id? That's what confuses me.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what you asked. Can you rephrase?

Comment: I think my problem is that when I bind (or ->sumbit in your example) to $disponibilite when I receive the POST request that it doesn't actually bind the linked entities.

For example :

When I load the form, I attach $evenement and $this->getUser() to the $disponibilite entity and then pass it to the form builder. so far so good.

When I submit my form, I expect that when I bind, the binding will bind the link entities objects since it was passed in the form. But printing $disponibilite->getEnsemble, gives me NULL. I am able to get $disponibilite->getRaison() wich is the comment text

Comment: Are you sure `getEvenement()` is not null before the binding? Form submision shouldn't replace `evenement` property since it's not even in the form type. Also I'll cahnged the line where $disponibilite is being getting from the db, try to test it. It should be `'evenement'=>$evenement` and not `'evenement'=>$id`

Comment: Yes it is NULL before the binding, and still is after the binding. Sry if it's confusing, because I changed a litte bit my code (it's still split). How you did it, you get related entity info from $id and $this->getUser(), but you don't get the info from the actual POST. I was expecting that Symfony would have bound the related entities (evenement and utilisateur) without doing $disponibilite->setEvenement and setUtilisateur in the sendDisponibiliteAction(). I thought Symfony have done this for me. But apparently these infos are not available in my POST data.

Comment: You can _make_ them available by adding hidden fields `user` and `event` in the `DisponibiliteType` but you **don't need** and highly not recomended to do that. It's common practice to set them via entity setters or via `$form->setData()`. Everything's ok with that. But when you add user and event fields to the form, users get ability to **manually change them** I'm pretty sure you don't want it to happen, do you? :)

Comment: Ok! that's exactly what I was wondering! So I will do it your way! That clarifies it all now! So my answer to myself is : No, Symfony will not automatically bind related entities. I must fetch them with info I have in hand. Thanks so much for all of your time. Very appreciated